# How to deactivate the caching from liferay in portal-ext.properties

Tags: caching, liferay

I am working with liferay and I would like to deactivate the cache while I am working with the liferay theme. I have been reading that there is an option in the portal-ext.properties that deactivates is but I am not able to find it or I am not able to make it work properly as I always have to go to the control panel and empty the cache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem and tested different options until I got it:

com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.cache.CacheFilter=false

Comment: It worked like charm! Now I don't need to do that in development all the time. Thanks!